# Integration by parts a function xF(x)dF(x)

Tags: integration

I believe the  expression
$$\int_{0}^{x*} x dF(x)\ - 2 \int_{0}^{x*} x(1-F(x)) dF(x)$$  simplifies by integration by parts to give
$$\int_{0}^{x*} F(x)dx \ - \int_{0}^{x*} [F(x)]^2dx.$$
However, I cannot obtain this result.

I am trying to integrate it as follows. First, I rearrange it to remove the first term:
\begin{multline}\int_{0}^{x*} x dF(x)\ - 2 \int_{0}^{x*} x(1-F(x)) dF(x)\ = \\ \int_{0}^{x*} x dF(x)\ - 2\int_{0}^{x*} x dF(x)\ + 2 \int_{0}^{x*} xF(x) dF(x). \end{multline}

This simplifies to
$$- \int_{0}^{x*} x dF(x)\ + 2 \int_{0}^{x*} xF(x) dF(x).$$

Given that $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$ and $F(x*) = 1$, I can integrate by parts, giving the expression
$$-x^* + \int_{0}^{x*} F(x) dx\ + 2 \int_{0}^{x*} xF(x) dF(x).$$

And then I am stuck.

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{d}(F(x)^2) = 2F(x)\mathrm{d}F(x)$. Then you can integrate by parts the last integral.

Comment: Do you mean this? 
$$-x^* + \int_{0}^{x*} F(x) dx\ + \int_{0}^{x*} x \frac{d[F(x)]^2}{dF(x)}dF(x).$$
and then:

$$-x^* + \int_{0}^{x*} F(x) dx\ + x^* - \int_{0}^{x*} [F(x)]^2dx.$$

Comment: That's it :) $\color{white}{}$

Comment: Thank you very much! But can I really do this with the second term? And why?

Comment: I mean, I always doubt if I can just simply divide and multiply by dx, especially when it is a complex function

Comment: That's just a change of variable $y = F^2$. Otherwise you can rewrite all the integrals thanks to $\mathrm{d}F(x) = f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ before integrating by parts in a more standard setup.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with kind help from Abezhiko, to get the result one should proceed as follows:

$$-x^* + \int_{0}^{x*} F(x) dx\ + \int_{0}^{x*} x\frac{d[F(x)]^2}{dF(x)} dF(x).$$

which simplifies by integrating the second term by parts:

$$-x^* + \int_{0}^{x*} F(x) dx\ + x^* - \int_{0}^{x*}[F(x)]^2 dx.$$

Cancelling $x^*$:

$$\int_{0}^{x*} F(x) dx\ - \int_{0}^{x*}[F(x)]^2 dx .$$

Comment: Please write your answer as an actual answer and not as a link to an image where your answer is posted.